# Converting dates between SQL Server and Postgres with Talend

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, talend

I have a Talend job that runs a query on a SQL Server database and then writes selected data into a Postgres database. I am using the tMap component to do the mapping. The SQL Server dates are in similar to `2014-01-20 11:34:26.0` (configured as '"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS" in Talend) and the Postgres dates yyyy-MM-dd.

When I run the job I get the following exception:

> [statistics] connected
> Batch entry 0 INSERT INTO "criticalcareepisodes" ("GivenName","FamilyName","height","weight","mrn","id","admissiondate") VALUES ("Adam","Apple",100,200.0,123456,nextval('CriticalCareEpisodes_id_seq'),2009-11-10 21:30:00.000000 +11:00:00) was aborted.  Call getNextException to see the cause.
> [statistics] disconnected
> Job ExtractSLICCriticalCareEpisode ended at 14:06 27/09/2014. [exit code=0]

It seems that for some reason, the date is not being formatted as I would have expected.  The exception is fairly obviously related to trying to push a date/time into a Postgres Date type - at least I think so.  I am sure I am missing something obvious here, but any assistance would be appreciated.

I have added some images that may help:
[image: Job layout and SQL]

[image: tMap configuration]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your job including the database output component configuration and schema?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I have added a couple of images.  I hope this helps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ken Hampson's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26071525/2291321) covers the Postgres part of the problem: you're trying to insert a timestamp into a  date field.

The problem is that you're trying to specify the intended format (yyyy-MM-dd) in the date pattern part of the Date type configuration in the schema. Talend actually holds the full date object at all times and the date pattern is merely for formatting purposes with Talend components such as a tLogRow that will then print the date in the format chosen.

To properly convert the date to a formatted string so you can send it to Postgres (which will implicitly convert the string into a date) you need to replace `row1.CCDateAdmit` with `TalendDate.formatDate("yyyy-MM-dd",row1.CCDateAdmit)`.

Comment: thank you - this is a great help!  For others I have added a null test row1.CCDateAdmit==null?null:TalendDate.formatDate("yyyy-MM-dd",row1.CCDateAdmit)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with *Talend*'s software, but, from a *Postgres* perspective, it looks like the `INSERT` is trying to insert a `timestamp` using the non-string literal **2009-11-10 21:30:00.000000 +11:00:00**, which isn't a valid thing to do in *Postgres*. `timestamp` literals need to be specified in string form (among other methods, but it can't be a non-string form like what is indicated in the log output).

One can do something similar in a string form, i.e. `'2009-11-10 21:30:00.000000 +11:00'`.

Why the *Talend* software is sending a non-string form `timestamp` like that may be a bug in that software, although it's not clear from the available information.

Here is an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/45612/1) which shows what I mean in more detail.

Note that this assumes that the log would properly delimit strings as they should be in the `INSERT` query, which isn't totally clear from the log (i.e. are *Adam* and *Apple* strings or not? As indicated, they aren't, but that's odd.

If they actually are strings, then the next step is to get exactly what the exception is, which apparently you need to call `getNextException` to determine.

Comment: Apologies, yes they are Strings - I have modified the question.  Thank you for the SQL example.  What I am actually trying to do is to take the date time type from the MS SQL server and convert into a Date only (not time component) on the Postgres server.  I think you are correct that Talend is trying to insert a timestamp into a date - but I am not sure why.